# how to layout 2 buttons

Tags: java, android, uitableview, android-layout

I want 2 buttons to appear in the center of the screen, but at the bottom of the screen..

Here is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:stretchColumns="@string/app_name">

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button android:text="History"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/button1"
            ></Button>
            <Button android:text="RecordSpending" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/button2"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"></Button>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want this whole layout to appear at the bottom of the screen..(no matter what phone resolution the user has)..

I want the two columns to be equal in size and the bottoms located in the center horizontally.

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, can you put some screenshots as to what you have currently and what you want?

Comment: 1) I want to center the two bottoms. 2) Put the whole thing at the bottom of the screen

Comment: How can i put two buttons at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put two buttons at the bottom of the screen you can do this, psuedo code add relevant attributes.

```
<!-- This is the parent layout -->    
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

     <!-- Layout for your buttons at bottom -->
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <!-- weight = 1 would mean both buttons are of equal width -->
        <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />        
        <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks , I changed the display to smething else.  so the key here is align parent bottom ..true...ooh thanks